# How to get a String with Java regular expression in brackets within brackets

Tags: java, regex

How can i get a String inside brackets. See code below.

```
String str = "C1<C2, C3<T1>>.C4<T2>.C5"
```

I need to get `C1<C2, C3<T1>>`, `C4<T2>`, and `C5`.

See code what I tried below

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(\\w+(<[^>]+>)?)(.\\w+(<[^>]+>)?)*");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);
```

but the result was

```
C1<C2, C3<T1>
```

Comment: I *think* this is possible if you limit the number of nested brackets to some fixed amount, like four levels of nesting.  Usually one uses a parser for this.

Comment: Sounds to me like you just want to split on `.`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @markspace is right. If you don't limit the possible nesting of brackets, this can not be expressed by regular expressions.

Comment: haha i agree with @shmosel completely, split around the period and you are good to go

Comment: @shmosel actually I split str on '.' first and I thought HOW I CAN SOVLE REGULAR EXPRESSION ON IT. thank you guys!!!

Comment: @shmosel I just want to solve this with REGEX :D I already solved this by splitting on `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems that I see with your code:

1. It seems like you are only printing the first match instead of
   looping through the results. Use `while(mat.find())` to iterate
   through the list of matches.
2. Simplify your pattern to `\\w+(<[^>]+>+)?` to get `C1<C2, C3<T1>>`, `C4<T2>`, and `C5`.

   RegEx pattern explained:

   - `w+`= 1 or more alphanumeric or underscore character
   - `()?` = 0 or 1 of what is in the parenthesis
   - `<` = match the `<` character
   - `[^>]+` = 1 or more sets characters until the `>` character
   - `>+` = 1 or more `>` character (An alternative would be `>{1,2}` if you want to enforce only either one or two `>` characters.)

Your resulting code should look like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str = "C1<C2, C3<T1>>.C4<T2>.C5";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\w+(<[^>]+>+)?");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);

    while(mat.find()) {
        System.out.println(mat.group());
    }    
}
```

---

If you just want a list of the parts though, a much simpler way to accomplish this would be to use `split()` instead of RegEx. You can split the string on `.`, save the pieces in an array and then iterate through the array as so desired.

That would be accomplished with the following:

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\.");
```

Comment: I think you mean `str.split ("\\.");`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I think I meant that too :) Thanks. Updated my answer.

Comment: @TotZam thank you so much !! I love this. I can't use split because of this cas, "C1<C2.C3, C3.C6<T1>>.C4<T2>.C5", so I used `Stack` finally. If you don't mind, may i have a question? What is (.+?)? What is different (.+) with (.+?) ?

Comment: @KimKevin Try testing out your expressions on http://regexr.com/. That site allows you to hover over each part of the expression and it very nicely explains what it means. In short, `(.+)` matches any character 1 or more times. With `(.+?)?`, the first `?` makes the proceeding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possibly, and the second `?` matches the entire expression in the parentheses 0 or 1 times. This is really a separate question, so if you want a more detailed explanation or have additional questions, ask a separate new question and I can try to help there.

Comment: @TotZam alright! thank u for ur explanation! so much helpful for me!

Comment: @KimKevin You can also check out [SO Regular Expressions Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics) for more explanation of the different RegEx symbols, specifically the part about [Lazy patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/429/greedy-and-lazy-patterns#t=201701060325301870191&a=parameters).

Answer (score 1):

Just split on dots:

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\.");
```

This does what you want using the sample input in the question.